# C++ STL and DLLs

Tags: c++, dll, stl

I know this question has been asked in a similar manner many times over, but I'm not positive I've fully grasped the concepts involved here. I'm currently working on something small as a bit of a learning project (since I stopped using C++ awhile back and want to get back into it) and from what I've read there are a bit of problems when using the STL in DLLs.

However, from what I've gathered there are two ways to avoid possible problems.

Method 1: Users of the DLL have to have the same compiler and same C Run time Library.

Method 2: Hide all STL class members from direct access.

However, when it comes to method 2, I know the STL class member cannot be accessed directly by  the client for this method to work, but does that mean:

```
//Note all the code in this example was written directly in my web broswer with no checking. 

#ifdef SAMPLEDLL_EXPORTS
#define SAMPLE_API __declspec(dllexport) 
#else
#define SAMPLE_API __declspec(dllimport) 
#endif

class SAMPLE_API SampleClass
{
  std::map<int, std::string> myMap;

  public:
  SampleClass();
  ~SampleClass();

   void addSomething(int in_Key, char* in_Val)
   {
     std::string s(in_Val);
     myMap.insert( std::pair<int, std::string>(in_Key, s) );
   };

   bool getHasKey(int in_Key)
   {
      return myMap.find(in_Key) != myMap.end(); 
   };

};
```

would work?

Comment: In the this specific case, yes, since all of the code is in the header, nothing in the DLL.  Probably not what you meant.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Hans Passant pointed out in a comment, your example is a bit questionable because you put all the method definitions inline.  But let's assume you move the definitions to a separate .cpp file which you then build into a DLL.

It won't be safe.

Right from the beginning, we have this:

```
class SAMPLE_API SampleClass
{
  std::map<int, std::string> myMap;
```

I didn't need to look any further, because we can see right away that the size of SampleClass depends on the size of std::map, and that is not specified by the standard.  So while you could say that SampleClass doesn't "expose" its map, it actually sort of does.  You could use the Pimpl technique to overcome this and truly hide the map from the ABI of your class.

Comment: Do you mind explaining how pimpl works exactly? Is it because the map is only in the implementation that pimpl works?

Comment: It's because the size of the map and therefore the size of the impl class will only need to be known in the compiled DLL, not to the API user.  This is because only the DLL will (de)allocate impl objects, use them, etc.  Pimpl just hides the implementation details more fully.